# Acquiring AUD traveller's cheques for Tuvalu in Fiji

Tags: money, australia, fiji

I am planning to spend two or three weeks in Tuvalu this June.

I understand there are no ATM facilities in Tuvalu and the local currency is the Australian Dollar.

I assume it would be safer to carry traveller's cheques in AUD, which I assume can be cashed at the bank in Funafati than a large quantity of cash.

Is it possible to acquire AUD traveller's cheques in Nadi or Suva in Fiji ?

Comment: Just curious... why not pay by card, and carry a small amount of AUD in cash?  Isn't that "safer" than carrying travellers' cheques?

Comment: I seriously doubt that plastic money is accepted anywhere in Tuvalu if they don't have an ATM - happy to be corrected though !

Comment: @eggyal most sites online point out how Tuvalu doesn't accept credit cards.  I had the same problem in Iran :/

Answer (score 9):

Was in Nadi airport 2 weeks ago. There's certainly an exchange place for money in the airport, so that's one option for obtaining Aussie dollars.

Second option is that all banks in Suva/Nadi [will readily accept travellers cheques](http://fijiguide.com/page/money-1).  Probably worth checking out the open times beforehand though.  If you were able to get Aussie travellers cheques, it'd likely be at the banks here.

Finally, if you get Aussie traveller cheques, [you can exchange them for cash at the National Bank of Tuvalu](http://www.timelesstuvalu.com/travel-to-the-tuvalu-islands), which opens from 10:00am to 2:00pm Mondays to Thursday and 9:00am to 1:00pm Fridays.

Comment: Thanks Mark. It looks like there is an ANZ branch in Suva so I might try contacting them...just wondering if anyone here had previous experience dealing with money in Tuvalu !